# Trocar de Botão com VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Quero fazer o seguinte:

Pessoa Clica no Botao `Contratar` que esta verde com *Bootstrap* ele muda a classe do botão.
Resumindo: Clicou no botao ele vira outro.

Qual método e evento devo fazer aqui... entendo sobre `v-bind` `v-on` eu sei disso, mas quero saber qual evento deve ter para trocar template tipo `change.Templateto(enviar)` algo assim...

com VUEJS por favor:

```
<div id="app">
   <botao-contratar></botao-contratar>
</div>

 <template id="contratar">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Contratar</a>
 </template>

 <template id="ativar">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Ativar</a>
 </template>
```

Parte do VUEJS:

```
          Vue.component('botao-contratar',{
            template: '#contratar',
          });

          Vue.component('botao-ativar',{
            template: '#ativar',
          });

          var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
              titulo: "vuejs",
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o [binding do Vue para classes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes) juntamente com uma variável booleana para fazer a alternância entre as classes que você deseja.

Veja no exemplo abaixo o uso do binding `:class` para alternar a classe do botão entre `btn-success` e `btn-outline-danger` (mais classes do Bootstrap para botões na [documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)).

HTML:

```
<div id="app" class="m-2">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" @click="isActive = !isActive" :class="{ 'btn-success': !isActive, 'btn-outline-danger': isActive }">Contratar</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    isActive: false
  }
});
```

Veja [aqui](https://codepen.io/tkrempser/pen/axdzbz) este exemplo em funcionamento.

Comment: Mas nesse caso o botão somente vai mudar de estilo. Teria que criar um method pra esse click, pra mudar a cor do botão e inserir alguma outra funcionalidade.

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que está falando, me parece mais um caso pra v-if ou v-show.

```html
<button v-if="metodo === 'contratar'" @click="mudarMetodo('ativar')">Contratar</button>
<button v-if="metodo === 'ativar'" @click="mudarMetodo('contratar')">Ativar</button>
```

VueJS:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    metodo: 'contratar'
  },
  methods: {
    mudarMetodo (tipoMetodo) {
       this.metodo = tipoMetodo
    }
  }
});
```